# Strange generic behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, generics

In the following code, boxing occurs (in Generic<Type>.Print):

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Generic<string> generic = new Generic<string>("test");
            generic.Print();
        }
    }

    class Generic<Type>
    {
        Type value;

        public Generic(Type value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

ILSpy output:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void Print () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x207d
    // Code size 17 (0x11)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld !0 class Test.Generic`1<!Type>::'value'
    IL_0006: box !Type
    IL_000b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    IL_0010: ret
} // end of method Generic`1::Print
```

It's boxing and calling Console.WriteLine(object).  I assumed that it would simply call Console.WriteLine(string).  What is going on here?

Comment: Looks like its using some code reuse.

Comment: Fyi, it is bad practice to call the generic parameter `Type`, because it can conflict with `System.Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its chosen the `object` overload for `Console.WriteLine` because this is the most appropriate overload for that call.

Remember that **overload resolution is done at compile time** - the compiler must choose a suitable  overload based on the provided type information, and in this situation the only suitable one is the `object` overload.

To understand this it may help to ignore your `Main` method and consider the case where the `Generic` class is in a different assembly.  The compiler needs to choose an overload and knows only that `Type` can either be cast or boxed into an `object`.  Just because there *is* in fact code elsewhere in the assembly that uses this class with a `string` type parameter doesn't affect the way that `Generic` is compiled.

Alternatively consider what would happen if `Console.WriteLine` didn't have an overload accepting an `object` - in this case the method simply would not compile (as there are no restrictions on `Type` which would make another overload suitable).

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer resolved one part of my question and Jon Skeet's answer resolved the other, but I can pick only one accepted answer.  Since your answer addresses the part I cared about slightly more, I picked yours.  All answers were helpful, however.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, it won't actually box. From the ECMA-335 description of the `box` instruction:

> If *typeTok* is a reference type, the box instruction does returns *val* unchanged as *obj*.

In other words, a `box` is harmless if you call it on a reference type.

(The JIT will be generating separate native code for reference types and value types anyway, so I suspect this just ends up being completely removed in the reference type version.)

Comment: +1 Yup, I see that in section 4.1. 'does returns', man they need some proof readers :P

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its reusing code.

You could try to force it not to do that.

```
public void Print<Type>()
{
   Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```